# Ruby Regular Expression To Ensure String Contains Comma Characters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I need to verify that a string has at least one comma but not more than 4 commas.

This is what I've tried:

```
/,{1,4}/

/,\s{1,4}/
```

Neither of those work.

Note: I've been testing my RegEx's on [Rubular](http://www.rubular.com)

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Note: I'm using this in the context of an Active Record Validation:

```
validates :my_string, format: { with: /,\s{1,4}/}
```

How can do this as an Active Record Validation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I too would suggest using `count`, but to address your specific question, you could do it thusly:

```
r = /^(?:[^,]*,){1,4}[^,]*$/

!!"eenee"[r]
  #=> false 
!!"eenee, meenee"[r]
  #=> true 
!!"eenee, meenee, minee, mo"[r]
  #=> true 
!!"eenee, meenee, minee, mo, oh, no!"[r]
  #=> false
```

- `(?:[^,]*,)` is a non-capture group that matches any string of characters other than a comma, followed by a comma;
- `{1,4}` ensures that the non-capture group is matched between 1 and 4 times;
- the anchor `^` ensures there is no comma before the first non-capture group; and
- `[^,]*$` ensures there is no comma after the last non-capture group.

Comment: getting the following error with that: ArgumentError: The provided regular expression is using multiline anchors (^ or $), which may present a security risk. Did you mean to use \A and \z, or forgot to add the :multiline => true option?

Comment: added multiline: true and it's working. any idea what the security risk here is?

Comment: I don't get any problems with Ruby 2.2 or Rubular, without `/m`.  It also works fine if I replace `^` with `\A` and `$` with `\z`, which makes sense because here the line and string are one and the same. I'm not familiar with security risks.

Answer (score 2):

Does it have to be a regex?  If not, use Ruby's `count` method:

```
> "a,a,a,a,a".count(',')
=> 4
```

Comment: To avoid Rails dependency, maybe `(2..4).cover? "a,a,a,a,a".count(',') #=> true`.

Comment: thanks - that's along the lines of what I'm trying to do. Any idea how to work this in to an active record validation?

Answer (score 2):

```
str ="a,b,a,,"
p str.count(",").between?(1, 4) # => true
```

Comment: thanks - that's along the lines of what I'm trying to do. Any idea how to work this in to an active record validation?

Comment: Writing custom validators are pretty easy. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#performing-custom-validations